# XML output data from Bing Maps/virtualearth.net API with Google Docs importXML

Tags: api, maps, bing-maps, bing

I've been using Google Docs' ImportXML function to retrieve data from MapQuest's API. Unfortunately MapQuest's API doesn't offer all the data that I need, which is why I want to use Bing Maps instead. I've been trying this:

```
=importXML("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=NL&postalCode=A2&key=$A$1&output=xml";"//Resources/Point/Latitude")
```

I'm getting a "imported content is empty" error, which I believe is being caused by an incorrect xpath-query. When I enter the URL in my browser manually, I do get to see correct XML output.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a case sensitivity related issue. Workaround is json output and using this Google Sheets script: https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a

Works perfectly.